# Why doesn't RESX editor work for me in Xamarin Studio Community

Tags: c#, xamarin, editor, resx

What I am trying now is to open RESX file with RESX Editor.

I followed the link below.

[Xamarin RESX editor](https://github.com/CalebMorris/Xamarin-ResxEditor)

But I cannot find anything in Xamarin Studio Community.
Specifically in Add-in repository (Alpha channel)

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: To my understanding, Caleb hasn't ported the ResX editor to Xamarin Studio 6. You should raise an issue on his repo to make him aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it only works on Xamarin Studio 5.

The owner of the Add-in will try to [port](https://github.com/CalebMorris/Xamarin-ResxEditor/issues/21) it to Xamarin Studio 6.